# Critique: Logo For Digital Agency

Tags: logo, critique

[image]

I am trying to create a logo for a digital marketing agency named as **THE MISFITS.**
I have tried to create *puzzle pieces* that *don't fit together.* what do you guys think?

Looking forward to feedback and criticism. :)

Comment: That's... ummm... suggestive. You probably don't want something where the first thing that many people are going to think is that your two pieces are having sex.

Comment: LoL :D I never looked it that way. so what you suggest I should do

Comment: As a logo, this design has **many** failures, too many to list here. But a good  start would be not to design from the own remote memory,  this can lead to situations where only the designer recognizes what the final result means. What do you think about having a look to real pieces of puzzle?

Comment: thank you so much, @Danielillo for your feedback and suggestion. I"m  a newb to graphics design and I am still learning. if you could recommend me a book to make my failures right that would be a great help.

Comment: I agree with @Makyen. It looks suggestive to me too. And personally I do not get a sense of trust from looking at the logo

Comment: Tip: Get paid ASAP. An agency with this name won't be in business very long. ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the big problems in the design is the range of scale you are using. It's useful when you design a logo to look at it in a small size to check if it's still legible. So for example, if I took your current image and scaled it down...

[image]

We can't see "The" and "Digital Agency" anymore. Also, the part of the puzzle where you are conveying the message of "misfitness" is a bit tougher to decypher.

Some suggestions for starters:

- Fix the issues where the type disappears at a smaller scale
- Simplify the symbol to focus on the "misfitness" -- the part where a square ans a circle are mixed (and clear up any confusion about sexual innuendos as posted in an earlier comment)